# Firebase : SendPassworResetEmail

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, reset-password

I am using firebase with java and in this case when using the "sendPasswordResetEmail" it does not send me the mail, I already checked and the email was taken from an editText, I already verified that the value of the email is taken correctly, I tested it with emails that I have registered and it always shows me a message that is in case the task is not successful.
This operation is executed in a pop-up:

```
private TextView confirmar;
private EditText correo;
private String sCorreo = "";
private FirebaseAuth fireAuth;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    fireAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pop_reset_password);
    confirmar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terminar_popResetP);
    correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.correo_popResetP);

    DisplayMetrics medidas = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(medidas);

    int ancho = medidas.widthPixels;
    int alto = medidas.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(ancho*0.85), (int)(alto*0.5));
}

public void Cerrar(View view){
    finish();
}

public void BtnReset(View view){
    sCorreo = correo.getText().toString();
    if(sCorreo.contains("@") && sCorreo.contains(".")){
        confirmar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pDialog.setMessage("Enviando enlace...");
        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pDialog.show();
        ResetPassword();
    }else {
        confirmar.setText("Ingrese correo electronico valido.");
        confirmar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public void ResetPassword (){
    fireAuth.setLanguageCode("es");
    fireAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(sCorreo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                //message: task is successful.
                confirmar.setText("Se ha enviado un correo para restablecer tu contraseña.");
                confirmar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else {
                //message: task not completed.
                confirmar.setText("El enlace de restablecimiento de contraseña no pudo ser enviado, 
                 verifique el correo escrito.");
                confirmar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

No matter the email you use to do the test, it always shows me the task not completed message and clearly no message reaches my email; It always shows me the negative answer as if the email was not valid or did not exist.

Comment: Are you sure that `sCorreo`contains the email you entered when `ResetPassword()` is run?

Comment: if I tried it by showing me a Toast and if it shows me the email as it is .Also try instead of placing sCorreo use correo.getText (). ToString ();

Comment: If you do a `task.getException().printStackTrace()` in the `else` block of `onComplete(...)`, what does it tell you?

Comment: Usually, to test my application I use an external device since the emulator consumes many resources, but today I tested with the emulator, it and it works fine when sending the email to reset my password, but when testing on my external device it doesn't work.  I don't know what it could be.

Comment: You can still get the stacktrace from the external device 